# How can I write a DataTemplate with list and page bindings in C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been asked to change some code to C# for Xamarin from XAML.

Is there anyone here who could give me advice on how I can do this.

Here's an example of what I have in XAML. MyGrid is a grid with a label inside of it written in C# that has a Text and a TappedCmd binding.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="thisPage">

<StackLayout
   BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfText}">
   <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <MyGrid Text="{Binding Text}" 
            TapCommand="{Binding 
            Path=BindingContext.TappedCmd, Source={x:Reference   Name=thisPage}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Is this something that's easy to do in C# and how can I do it or at least can someone give me some example of similar code that I can use to work from.

Comment: the docs demonstrate how to create templates using both methods - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like below:

```
public YourPage()
  {
    
      var viewModel = ...;

      var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
      {
         var mygrid = new MyGrid ();
         mygrid.SetBinding(MyGrid.TextProperty, "Text");
         mygrid.SetBinding(MyGrid.TapCommandProperty, new Binding("TappedCmd", source: viewModel));
         return mygrid;
      });
      StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
      BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(stackLayout, viewModel.ListOfText);
      BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate(stackLayout, dataTemplate);
      Content = stackLayout;
  }
```

you could refer to [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)

Comment: Thanks, this got me further and your answer is correct.  However I notice there is a problem because  the source of my data viewModel.ListOfText is not actually a List it is: public ObservableCollection<TestViewModel> ListOfText;

Comment: @Janice_Feb_1998 It doesn't matter. They all implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: okay I found out what makes it work and not work.  Seems like it only works if I populate my ListOfText in the Constructor of the ViewModel.  I had this being done in the OnAppearing and when there no data would show.  I will formulate another question and ask for help there.  Thanks

Comment: @Janice_Feb_1998 I have give a reply in your new question,you should make sure you set data-binding after you populate the data.

Comment: I see a lot of examples where the collection is changed and the data-binding is not set again with XAML.  For these the output changes but it doesn't seem to work in C#.